# i would like to use return on a form and want to know how to use return key on a button

Tags: javascript

I want to assign the return key to 'button' as well as 'click' on a mouse. Please help.

```
  var input = document.querySelector('input');
  var btn = document.querySelector('button');
  var para = document.querySelector('p');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var code = input.value;
    para.textContent = eval(code);
  });
```

Comment: Not clear what exactly is needed.

Comment: you mean the keyboard

Comment: Yes, the keyboard. I want to the result of the input when i press the return key. Not just the click with the mouse. The code above has a 'click' event. How can i have both these work on the 'button'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add keyup event listener on your field

```js
 var input = document.querySelector('input');
  var btn = document.querySelector('button');
  var para = document.querySelector('p');
  function run() {
   var code = input.value;
    para.textContent = eval(code);
  }
  btn.addEventListener('click', run);
  
  input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) run()
  })
```

```html
<input>
<button>Eval</button>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Excellent! It worked. Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `addEventListener` to bind the `keyup` event to the input. `e.keyCode == 13` will check if the key pressed is enter, whose key code is 13. It will then execute the code.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var para = document.querySelector('p');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var code = input.value;
  console.log(code)
  para.textContent = eval(code);
});
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var code = input.value;
    console.log(code)
    para.textContent = eval(code);
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button type="button">Submit</button>
<p>Result</p>
```